# Heroku Golang - command 'main' not found

Tags: heroku, go, buildpack

I got a Go API up on Heroku to which I push some code; in my procfile I have the following

```
web: main
```

In order to launch the Go built binary on Heroku's side. When I build it on my side with

```
go build cmd/main.go
```

It produces a binary file namned 'main' in my project root and works as expected but on Heroku I get

```
app[web.1]: bash: main: No such file or directory
```

The build process on Heroku seems fine, it finds all my dependencies and installs/compiles it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was super simple once I realised this;

> All main packages in the repo are compiled and binaries placed in the /app/bin directory, which is in the PATH. **Binaries are named after the directory that contains them.**

Comment: yes, Heroku basically does "go install ./..." which does exactly that, make a binary named after the dir that contains go files with the package declared as main

Comment: I have the same error and can't make it work. I tried different names, but nothing happens, still `not found`...

Comment: Incase this might help others, it meant having a Procfile that looked like: "web: <app-directory-name>"

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note: Like other Go programs, the code in `main.go` has to belong to package `main`:

```
package main

func main() {
    // your code here
}
```

I'm afraid I totally forgot about this at first and it stumped me for a while.